# What are the differences between the Eurail Pass and the Interrail Pass, aside from who is eligible to buy them?

Tags: trains, europe, interrail, eurail

https://www.eurail.com/en/help/interested-in-eurailing/do-i-need-a-eurail-or-an-interrail-pass mentions Eurail Pass and Interrail Pass have the same price:

> European citizens can use an Interrail Pass instead, available from [Interrail.eu](https://www.interrail.eu/en) for the same price as a Eurail Pass.

https://www.acprail.com/blog/2010/12/faq-whats-the-difference-between-a-eurail-and-interrail-pass/ mentions a few differences (I removed the difference they mentioned about the network, which I believe is nowadays the same):

> The validities, or number of travel days, to choose from is also different for these two passes. Furthermore, InterRail does not offer Regional or Select Passes where Eurail does, but InterRail do offer a larger selection of One Country Passes.

Are there any other differences between [Eurail Pass](https://www.eurail.com/en/eurail-passes) and [Interrail Pass](https://www.interrail.eu/en/interrail-passes), aside from who is eligible to buy them?

Comment: Are these the up to date pages?

Comment: @Willeke no: the difference they mentioned about the network is out-of-date.

Comment: I heard a few years ago that the two passes were going to be merged, then Covid came and I lost track.

Comment: @Willeke interesting, that'd make sense as https://www.interrail.eu/en/interrail-passes and https://www.eurail.com/en/eurail-passes look very similar.

Comment: The only difference I can see is that the Interrail OCPs can't be taken for less than 3 days, where as 1 and 2 days Eurail passes are available

Answer (score 1):

Interrail passes can only be bought by European residents. Eurail Passes by non residents. Citizenship actually does not matter, as eg. a French resident of the US can buy a Eurail Pass. It is where you live that matters, not what your nationality is.

But the other major difference is that the Interrail pass only gives you unlimited travel outside your own country. It is not valid in your own country of residence except for two trips, which have to be for the purpose of leaving (or entering) your country.